# How to change the timing of the rigid body falling?

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, timeline

I'm using blender 2.79b which is fantastic, I'm a student and I'm learning the software by myself and I had a problem about the timing of the body falling using rigid body.

How can I change the starting point for the object to fall.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange, you could help us answer your question by adding a screenshot and perhaps adding a sketch of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the Rigid body cache in the scene tab. That is where you can adjust which frame when the simulation starts. Use the bake button after you adjusted the values to recalculate the physics.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I usually animate the Animated property on the rigid body. 
You can then animate multiple objects with individual starting points.

This will also allow you to animate the object a few frames first if you want it to be thrown in a direction.

[image]